# Long living Entity Framework context - best practice to avoid data integrity issues

Tags: wpf, winforms, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

As a very rudimentary scenario, let's take these two operations:

```
UserManager.UpdateFirstName(int userId, string firstName)
{
    User user = userRepository.GetById(userId);
    user.FirstName = firstName;
    userRepository.SaveChanges();
}

InventoryManager.InsertOrder(Order newOrder)
{
    orderRepository.Add(newOrder);
    orderRepository.SaveChanges();
}
```

I have only used EF in web projects and relied heavily on the stateless nature of the web.  With every request I would get a fresh copy of the context injected into my business layer facade objects (services, managers, whatever you want to call them), all of the business managers sharing the same instance of the EF context.  Currently I am working on a WPF project and I'm injecting the business managers and subsequently the repositories that they use directly into the View Model.

Let's assume a user is on a complicated screen and his first button click calls the UpdateFirstName() method.  Let's assume SaveChanges() fails for whatever reason.  Their second button click will invoke the InsertOrder() method.

On the web this is not an issue as the context for operation #2 is not related (new http request) to the context used by operation #1.  On the desktop however, it's the same context across both actions.  The issue arises in the fact that the user's first name has been modified and as such is tracked by the context.  Even though the original SaveChanges() didn't take (say the db was not available at that time), the second operation calling SaveChanges() will not only insert the new order, it will also update the users first name.  In just about every cause this is not desirable, as the user has long forgotten about their first action which failed anyway.

This is obviously being a silly example, but I always tend to bump into these sort of scenarios where I wish I could just start fresh with a new context for every user action as opposed having a longer lived (for the life of the WPF window for example) context.

How do you guys handle these situations?

Answer (score 3):

A very real interrogqation when coming from ad hoc desktop apps that hit the database directly.

The answer that seems to go with the philosophy for ORMs is to have a context that has the same lifespan as your screen's.
The data context is a Unit Of Work implementation, in essence. For a web app, it is obviously the request and it works well.

For a desktop app, you could have a context tied to the screen, or possibly tied to the edit operation (between loading and pressing "save"). Read only operations could have a throwaway context (using IDs to reload the object when necessary, for example when pressing a "delete button" in a grid).
Forget about a context that spans the entire application's life if you want to stay aware of modifications from other users (relationship collections are cached when first loaded).
Also forget about directly sharing EF entities between different windows, because that effectively makes it an app-wide and thus long lived context.

It seems to me ORMs tend to enforce a web-like design on desktop apps because of this. No real way around this I'm afraid.
Not that it is necessary a bad thing in itself. You should normally not be attacking the database at the desktop level if it is to be shared between multiple instances. In which case you would be using a service layer, EF would be in its element and your problem would be shifted to the "service context"...

Comment: Dennis, in fact my question is about one context per window, I am not even considering sharing it across anything more than that.  I am simply wondering regarding the "state" that context maintains for the life of the window.  Many windows have unrelated operations, some might fail, others we simply want to abandon (after modifying some entities tracked by the context, yet not calling Savechanges).  It feels right to me to maintain a context per window approach, I just don't see how it can really work for me without causing endless data integrity issues.

Comment: Okay, re-reading your original question and your comment, EF has some way to deal with failures and clean-up, by refreshing entities (with various options about who wins regarding local modifications).

Comment: Indeed it does Denis, however unless you're directly playing with the context in your View Model as opposed to going through a business layer that contains a generic repository that contains the EF context, it becomes nearly impossible to use such fine grained features.  I guess I was hoping for more hands on experience comments.  I'm sure I'm not the only one that doesn't go through WCF services to the database.

Comment: I know, it's infuriating the number of "tutorials" or "samples" that only go so far and leave you wanting for more...

Comment: It becomes a little more complicated when using caching. For example : the database is accessed through internet, and you need to pull quite a large amount of data each time because calculations are made. I chose to handle the caching myself, and use a context as the cache, that I refresh from time to time. I dont know if this is a good idea, but it seems to be working pretty well for an adhoc solution

Answer (score 2):

We have a large WPF application that calls WCF services to perform CRUD operations like ‘UpdateFirstName()’ or ‘InsertOrder()’. Every call into the service creates a new ObjectContext, therefore we don’t need to worry about inconsistent ObjectContexts hanging around.

Throw away the ObjectContext as soon as you are done with it. Nothing’s wrong with generating a new ObjectContext on the fly. There’s unnoticeable overhead in creating a new ObjectContext and you’ll save yourself many future bugs and headaches.

Suppose you do create a new ObjectContext each time a method is called on your repository, the below snippet would still give you transaction support by using the TransactionScope class. For example,

```
        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            UserManager.UpdateFirstName(userid,firstName);
            InventoryManager.InsertOrder(newOrder);

            scope.Complete();
        }
```

Comment: Chris I am avoiding a true WCF tier as I don't see it necessary for this particular application.  That said I can obviously replicate the same behavior without true disconnected services (in memory layer can work just the same).  What do you guys do in a situation where you want a "business operation/transaction" to span multiple services and one commit/rollback at the end?  The beauty of my approach is all my business layer managers (services if you will) share the same data context underneath, therefore I can utility unit of work to issue one SaveChanges() call at the end.

Comment: In our case, we can set a couple attributes on our WCF service classes and we automatically get transaction support across multiple services and machines. WCF was made for this kind of thing. In your case you have your repositories in-process, so you could wrap your repository calls in a TransactionScope. I edited my answer to illustrate what I mean.

Comment: Interesting, I suppose my follow up question was unrelated to my original but it's good to know WCF has this feature built in.

Answer (score 0):

One completely different way is writing all changes to the database directly (with short lived database contexts). And then add some kind of draft/versioning on top of that. That way you can still offer ok/undo/cancel functionality.